# Few questions about Keras documentation

Tags: keras

In Keras documentation named activations.md, it says "Activations can either be used through an Activation layer, or through the activation argument supported by **all forward layers**.". Then what is the meaning of **forward layers**? I think some layers don't have an activation parameter.(ex. Dropout layer)

And "Activations that are more complex than a simple TensorFlow/Theano/CNTK function (eg. learnable activations, **which maintain a state**) are available as Advanced Activation layers, and can be found in the module keras.layers.advanced_activations. These include PReLU and LeakyReLU.". Then what is the meaning of **state** in this case?

Comment: Forward layers in a CNN are Convolutional layer, Dense layer, etc among others. These are the layers in a feed forward neural networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure there is a strict definition of "forward layers" in this context, but basically what it means is that the "classic", keras-built-in types of layers comprising one or more sets of weights used to transform an input matrix into an output one have a `activation` argument. Typically, `Dense` layers have one, as well as the various kinds of RNN and CNN layers.

It would not make sense for Dropout layers to have an activation function : they simply add a mechanism triggered at training to (hopefully) improve convergence rate and decrease overfitting chances.

As for the idea of "maintaining a state", it refers to activation functions that would not behave independently on each and every fed-in sample, but would instead retain some learnable information (the so-called *state*). Typically, for a LeakyReLU activation, you could adjust the leak parameter through training (and it would, in the documentation's terminology, be referred to as a *state* of this activation function).